# Google map inside a Listview

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview

I am developing an application where I need to use Google Maps as list-items inside a listview but am not able to create it like we usually do with other views(Like TextView,ImageView etc. as single row of a listview).
Any suggestions please!

Comment: you should not put a map in a list, instead you should use `LiteMode` and show a image of the map at the location you want, clicking on the list item should then take you to an activity with the full map. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite

Comment: Thanks for the solution but as I am using it inside an Adapter for Listview it's giving me error only.

Comment: Here is my Logcat output: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #23: Duplicate id 0x7f0c0078, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
Please guide me how can I achieve it in a listview.Thanks